# how to create one end to end application in angular/node/mongoDB and deploy it to heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I need to create one demo app which will have the technology stack as

UI: angular.js
backend: node.js
Database: MongoDB

I can use Github to store the repository and need to deploy it on heroku.

can anyone suggest me how can i Do that?

Comment: You may like to have a look http://mean.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many tutorials for this. Just look on the Heroku website if your problem is that you don't know how to deploy (Look at the Heroku git toolbelt), if your problem is that you don't know how to make a MEAN app (MongoDb, Express, Angular and Node) then I can forward you to this tutorial which I found really helpful https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application and https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial. I would also advise that you look into technologies such as Gulp and using Typescript with AngularJs if you weren't already.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the Gulp and the Typescript.